# Creating audio / a sound from a string

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Im trying to create audio from a string, im trying to make an example where a user enters their name which is then tunred into a sound / audio - the sound / audio would be different depending upon the string entered. (Im not looking to do 'text to speech' on the string, just create a sound which is generated by the string ie. sam would be a different sound to john or samuel.)

Ive been looking through the docs and libaries of several languages but couldn't find any thing that seems to do the above, i dont mind if its server or client side (although if its server side i guess the audio will need to be saved as a sound file (mp3?) passed to the client and played using js / html5)

Any ideas on how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at System.Speech in .Net... Basically though, the sort of code you're looking for is known as "TextToSpeech", or "TTS".

In terms of Javascript TTS, have a look at these :

http://www.jtalkplugin.com/

http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/